# React - Size of text and elements for different screens resolutions

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, responsive-design, screen-resolution

I'm develeoping a React website in a 1080p screen.
According to that size everything is good but once I scale it down to 720p the contents just overflow a lot into each other.
And when I move to a 1440p screen, everything just seems so little (mainly the text).
I've been using mainly REM's for sizing everything because I thought it would help with screen responsiveness.

What's the best way to have a similar looking screen with different resolutions?

1080p Screenshot
[image: 1440P Image]

720p Screenshot
[image: 70p Image]

1440p Screenshot
[image: 1440p Image]